# SQL QUERY Inner Join missing data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help getting this SQL Query to work

All tags are listed in the table Tag, but my joins is causing this trouble.
Please let me know how to list both type 1 (Discrete - no units) and type 2 (Analog with units) in the same query.

This is the current result:

```
wwTagKey TagName                        Description               TagType   Unit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
527      Æ0_0_02_VEN_MR6_02_Q.IO.HIL    High Limit Alarm Level    1         % rH
532      Æ0_0_02_VEN_MR6_02_Q.IO.LOL    Low Limit Alarm Level     1         % rH
547      Æ0_0_02_VEN_MR6_02_Q.IO.PV     Relative humidity         1         % rH
541      Æ0_0_02_VEN_MR6_03_Q.IO.HIL    High Limit Alarm Level    1         % rH
```

I need all tags with `TagType` no. 1 to included in this result, but this type (Discrete) does not include a Unit.

Regarding this EUKey (Unit), then the database does not contain a table where Unit and wwTagKey are related, which is why I have joined the Tagname.

```
SELECT
    Tag.wwTagKey
    ,Tag.TagName
    ,Tag.Description
    ,Tag.TagType
    ,EngineeringUnit.Unit
FROM
    [Runtime].[dbo].[Tag]
INNER JOIN 
    [Runtime].[dbo].[AnalogTag] ON .AnalogTag.TagName = Tag.TagName
INNER JOIN 
    [Runtime].[dbo].[EngineeringUnit] ON AnalogTag.EUKey = EngineeringUnit.EUKey            
WHERE 
    TagType < 3;
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result to your question (as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Tip: table aliases are very convenient. Makes queries easier to write and to read.

Comment: Tagged as SQL Server because of the syntax observed and dbo schema. If wrong, please rollback.

Comment: I think that in general you should use numeric keys to join tables, rather then text keys

Comment: what is the error? do you get an empty result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate your query into two and use union

```
SELECT wwTagKey, TagName, Description, TagType, e.Unit
FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[Tag]
INNER JOIN [Runtime].[dbo].[AnalogTag] a ON a.TagName = Tag.TagName
INNER JOIN [Runtime].[dbo].[EngineeringUnit] e ON a.EUKey = e.EUKey           
WHERE TagType = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT wwTagKey, TagName, Description, TagType, ‘’
FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[Tag]
WHERE TagType = 1;
```

Alternatively you can you use left join but without knowing your data I can’t tell if you need to replace the first or the second or both inner joins with left joins.

Comment: UNION ALL does not remove duplicates when compared to UNION. Use accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `LEFT JOIN` do what you want?

```
SELECT t.wwTagKey, t.TagName, t.Description, t.TagType,
        eu.Unit
FROM [Runtime].[dbo].[Tag] t LEFT JOIN
     [Runtime].[dbo].[AnalogTag] ant
     ON ant.TagName = t.TagName LEFT JOIN 
     [Runtime].[dbo].[EngineeringUnit] eu
     ON ant.EUKey = au.EUKey            
WHERE t.TagType IN (1, 2);
```